# How to fix 500 server errors on spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller

I wrote these webservices and I tested them on postman, but I encountered error 500 on the test of creation, login, findbyId and delete. But the findAll method goes without problem.

I would like to have the fixes of the different methods if there is no if you can explain the problems.

This is spring-boot 2.2.0

```
package com.bni.Gestion_Operation.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.bni.Gestion_Operation.entities.Utilisateur;
import com.bni.Gestion_Operation.repositories.IUtilisateur;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/utilisateur")
public class UtilisateurController {
    @Autowired
    private IUtilisateur utilisateurRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity findAll() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(utilisateurRepository.findAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{matricule}")
    public ResponseEntity findUtilisateurById(@PathVariable(name="matricule") String matricule) {
        if (matricule == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Impossible de recuperer un utilisateur null");
        }
        Utilisateur utilisateur = utilisateurRepository.getOne(matricule);
        if (utilisateur == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(utilisateur);
    }

    @PostMapping("/cree")
    public ResponseEntity creeUtilisateur(@RequestBody Utilisateur utilisateur) {
        if (utilisateur == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Impossible de recuperer un utilisateur null");
        }
        Utilisateur utilisateurCree = utilisateurRepository.save(utilisateur);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(utilisateurCree);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{matricule}")
    public ResponseEntity supprimerUtilisateur( @PathVariable(name="matricule") String matricule) {
        if (matricule == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Impossible de supprimer un utilisateur, matricule null");
        }
        Utilisateur utilisateur = utilisateurRepository.getOne(matricule);
        if (utilisateur == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Utilisateur supprimé avec succès!");
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity login( @RequestParam(name="matricule") String matricule, @RequestParam(name = "password") String password) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(matricule) || StringUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Veuilez renseigner votre login et votre mot de passe SVP");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Connexion reussi avec succès!");
    }
}
```

Comment: HTTP status 500 is an error on the server side, did you check the logs ?

Comment: Show us 1. The request you're sending; 2. The stack trace

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/m2ebgbl) @MatheusCirillo

Comment: No I did not check the log. can you show me the way to the log. @Arnaud

Comment: Looks like you need to enable POST method on your web server.

Answer (score 0):

You're not mapping any `/utilisateur` with the HTTP method `POST`.

Send the same request to `/utilisateur/cree` and it will work.

Or just remove `/cree` from the annotation in the `creeUtilisateur` method.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity creeUtilisateur(@RequestBody Utilisateur utilisateur) {
    if(utilisateur==null) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Impossible de recuperer un utilisateur null");
    }
    Utilisateur utilisateurCree = utilisateurRepository.save(utilisateur);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(utilisateurCree);
}
```